# inserting data from two tables into one

Tags: sql, ms-access, command, conditional-statements

My question is:

I have 3 tables

`Workers_Day`, `Workers_Night`, `Total`

In `workers_Day` table:

```
ID, Name, Day_one, Day_two
```

In `workers_Night` table:

```
ID, Name, night_one, night_two
```

the fields will be filled with `1` or `0`  (`0` being  absent and `1` being working)

and `TOTAL`

```
ID, Name, Total_days_working, Total_nights_Working, Total
```

I want to insert data from the table 1 and 2  to the table 3..
I made a queries like this but it doesn't work

```
insert into total (Id, name, Total_days_working, Total_nights_working, Total)
Select id,name,
IIf([day_one]>0,1,0)+IIf([day_two]>0,1,0) as day_workings,
IIf([night_one]>0,1,0)+IIf([night_two]>0,1,0) as Total_nights_working,
Total_days_working+Total_nights_working AS Total
From Workers_day,Workers_night
Where Workers_day.id = Workers_night.id
```

the condition doesnt always is true..

sometimes there are different workers in the tables
but the problem start when  the worker "John" with ID "3"  is in both tables (Day ,night)

Comment: Please tell us, which database you are using.

Comment: im using access,   im doing the queries there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 mistake in your code

the correct is:

```
insert into total (Id, name, Total_days_working, Total_nights_working, Total)
Select Workers_day.id,Workers_day.name,
IIf([day_one]>0,1,0)+IIf([day_two]>0,1,0) as Total_days_working,
IIf([night_one]>0,1,0)+IIf([night_two]>0,1,0) as Total_nights_working,
Total_days_working+Total_nights_working AS Total
From Workers_day,Workers_night
Where Workers_day.id = Workers_night.id
```

Comment: thanks for fix it..  but now.. that quey only inser the data IF the ids are the same in both table..  what if there are differents workers in the tables?

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
IIf([day_night]>0,1,0)+IIf([day_night]>0,1,0) as Total_nights_working,
```

The column `day_night` does not exist. I think you meant `night_one` and `night_two`.